# Install of remote ceiling fan to single switch

Tags: wiring

So I need to know if this is correct I have hooked my white wire to solid wire and the black wire to the strand wire coming from
The ceiling to the transmitter of my ceiling fan the rest of the output wires color matches to the motor . The two green ground wires im
Not sure where to attach them?

Comment: You wire it safely to the ceiling by providing pictures of everything involved so we can see what's going on and not have to go by what you believe.

Comment: naked copper is ground. You need power from switch to the remote. Normally those would be black and white, The remote output wires go to the fan

Comment: This question needs pictures so we can see what you're dealing with. It will be almost impossible to answer otherwise.

Comment: Make/model # of fan would help too.